# SAS script: How to plot random intercepts in logistic glimmix models?

Tags: logistic, data-visualization, sas, random-effects-model

I have the following script:

```
proc glimmix;
class A B;
model Y = X/ dist=binary link=logit ddfm=bw solution;
random intercept / subject=A type = un solution ; covtest/wald;
random intercept / subject=B type=un solution ; covtest/wald;
output out=glimmixout_3 pred( blup )=PredProb/
                    pred(noblup )=PredProb_PA;
run;
```

Then,

```
ods html;
proc sgplot data=glimmixout_3;
scatter y=PredProb_PA x=X/group=A name="aaa";by A;
keylegend "dados"/title="aaa";
run;
ods html close;
```

I have 13 subjects (random effect). I get linear intercepts but when I plot all random effects together (group=A in the abobe example) I did not get parallel lines. I expected to see the variance of the random effects but, instead, all the lines are together. Where is my mistake?

The variance estimates in each subject (sigma^2):
A: 0.1982
B: 0.7207

Comment: Can you describe the data setup better (eg show some rows of the data)? How do variables `A` and `B` relate to the subject random effect?

Comment: A1 30/08/2011 1 -5,52 Where variable A is a slaughterhouse (A1) and B date of sample (repetition) nested within each slaughterhouse. Y is dichotomic and X is in log (continuous).

Comment: What are the variance estimates? Your result is consistent with sigma^2=0. It is easier if you edit your question instead of answering in the comments - this way others can see it more clearly.